# Exporting contents of QGIS relation?

Tags: qgis, export, relates

I have created a 1:many relation in QGIS 2.10.1 with Project Properties>Relations.  When I select a map feature with the Identify Features tool, a Feature Attributes window (widget?) appears.

How do I export the contents of that window to a new table?

---

Let me show an example:  I have created a 1:many relation.  I then identified a polygon feature (#1).  On the resulting output window, I click the button (#2), to format it's contents as a table.

I want to copy the contents of that window to the QGIS Layers list as a .dbf attribute table, but I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want as output - a new layer (table) in the QGIS Layers list, or to copy the feature attributes somewhere else (like a spreadsheet)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Please re-read the answer I gave below - I've re-ordered it to make your solution a bit easier to find.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options depending on what you want - both involve using 'select' instead of identify.

#### To create a new table in QGIS

1. Select the feature or features you are interested in;
2. Right-click and 'save-as', and make sure you select 'save only selected features' and 'add saved file to map'; for your example, select "DBF" as the output type.

[image]

#### To get the Identify results in a usable form outside QGIS

1. Select the feature or features you are interested in;

[image]

2. Select Edit | Copy;

[image]

3. Paste the resulting text into a spreadsheet (Libreoffice / Excel).

If you want the results in the spreadsheet to resemble the Attributes widget format, then 'paste special' and select 'transpose'.

[image]